# What event do I need to supress to stop IE from “Dinging” when I press enter in a textfield?

Tags: internet-explorer, events, extjs, extjs3, audio

I have absolutely the same problem as described here: [What event do I need to supress to stop IE from "Dinging" when I press enter in a text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952511/what-event-do-i-need-to-supress-to-stop-ie-from-dinging-when-i-press-enter-in)
But i'm using ExtJS and i don't understand which event i should use for fix this problem. I have tried all key events(keypress, keyup and keydown) but it doesn't work.

Do somebody know how to fix it? Without disable system sounds.

Comment: What version of Extjs?  This is not present on 4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, solution in my case is switch from "xtype: form" to "xtype: panel". After that sound are disappeared.

But I guess the solution can be applied not in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a setting in the Control Panel causing the issue. Try the following;

Control Panel -> Sound -> Sounds (tab) -> Sound Scheme -> Windows Default

Click Apply, OK, then maybe even log out and back in. Then give it a go.

Comment: NO! I know how i can disable system sound, but i need fix the issue in JS code.